# How to use Navigation Component in Customized Layout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I am making an app look like this.

[image: v]

The round things are buttons. And the green part is Fragment.

And my `host_navigation.xml` consists of A, B, C Fragment.

Those fragments belong to `MainActivity` ( And of course, it has `fragment` view ) And there is not `<action>`( No lines between fragments in design ) because I want to open each of fragments randomly. For example, A->B, B->A C->A, ... Wherever you are, you can mo to a specific fragment.

The three round buttons also belong to the `MainActivity`.

I've found `BottomNavigationView` or `NavigationView` Samples. However, they don't seem something that I can use in this layout. But the behavior is quite similar. just the layout is different.

How can I implement this and how can I also manage the stack behavior naturally? Like, back button and I'd like to keep the last 3 fragments and remove all the previous ones in stack.

+

This is my `host_navigation.xml` (It doesn't have actions.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/host_navigation"
            app:startDestination="@id/aFragment">
    <fragment android:id="@+id/aFragment"
              android:name="com.example.AFragment"
              android:label="fragment_a"
              tools:layout="@layout/fragment_a"/>

    <fragment android:id="@+id/bFragment"
              android:name="com.example.BFragment"
              android:label="fragment_b"
              tools:layout="@layout/fragment_b"/>

    <fragment android:id="@+id/cFragment"
              android:name="com.example.CFragment"
              android:label="fragment_c"
              tools:layout="@layout/fragment_c">
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

And this is `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_tab_area"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="105dp">

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_a"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50sp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_a"
                    android:margin="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_a"
            />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_b"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_a"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_b"/>

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_c"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_c"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rl_tab_area"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/host_navigation">
    </fragment>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I guess I need to use this in `MainActivity`

```
val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this@MainActivity, R.id.host_navigation)
```

If if use `NavigaitonBottomView` Then, I can pass this value to it but I have no idea now because I don't use it.

I tried to call other fragments by this

```
Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment).navigate(R.id.aFragment)
```

And tried

```
Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.host_navigation).navigate(R.id.aFragment)

Navigation.findNavController(R.id.host_navigation).navigate(R.id.aFragment)

findNavController(R.id.host_navigation).navigate(R.id.aFragment)
```

And other ways too. But none of them worked so far.

Comment: What about drawer layout ?

Comment: That can be perfectly be done if you include your black layout on the Activity that will be holding the fragments that will navigate

Comment: How do you want  to navigate ? Buttons in fragment or a side drawer layout with links to other fragments ?

Comment: @SyedAhmedJamil I don't use drawer.

Comment: @SyedAhmedJamil If you click each buttons(round) it moves to A fragment, B fragment, C fragment respectively.

Comment: @c-an I would suggest that you read how fragments work and how one can add,remove and replace fragments at runtime https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui. What you need to do is to set a click listener on all Buttons and in that listeners you must replace the current displaying fragment with another fragment respective to the button using Fragment Manager. Read the docs on Fragments for better understanding. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.

Comment: @c-an Your question is too broad. I mean there are a lot of ways to achieve this. Simplest way I have described by using a Fragment Manager to add or replace fragments at run time. On the other hand there is a new component called Navigation Component whose sole purpose is to aid in navigation in your app from simple to complex navigation. It comes with a visual navigation editor where you can define the flow of actions. This is the overview https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation. And this is how to use it https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Comment: @c-an It would be nice if you show some progress by using the info what is already available in android docs and online tutorials and articles. If you get stuck somewhere in a particular thing that you have tried or not getting the expected result. Then you can always update your question and we will be glad to help.

Comment: @SyedAhmedJamil Thanks for the links. And I updated. Please check. And I'd like to use `Navigation Component` of Jetpack.

Comment: u can try with action app:launchSingleTop="true"in navigation/fragment xml

Answer (score 0):

Set actions for all fragments in this way:

```
<navigation
    ...
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_a"
        android:label="fragment_a"
        android:name="com.example.AFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_a">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/a_to_b"
            app:destination="@id/fragment_b"
            app:launchSingleTop="true"/>
        <action
            android:id="@+id/a_to_c"
            app:destination="@id/fragment_c"
            app:launchSingleTop="true"/>
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

or instead single top u can use `app:popUpTo`

Then start them by navController:

```
navController.navigate(FragmentAFragmentDirections.aToC())
```